# How to compare a floats first 14 digits after the decimal point to another floats first 14?

Tags: python

Want to keep a while loop running while my current Xsub's first 14 digits after the decimal point are NOT equal to the previous Xsub's first 14 digits. Once they are equal the while loop will terminate.

Comment: Use the `str` function to change the floats to strings. in strings, you can specify the position of your number. You can use `float` function to change your string to a float again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-485-a-function-for-testing-approximate-equality